# How to split string into chunks and create a list of these chunks haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm completely new to Haskell so sorry if this seems like a silly question
I'm trying to create a function which takes a string, and splits the string into 5 pieces or chunks (assume string is always divisible by 5). then, create a list of string of those chunks.
I have this so far which I know is wrong, as I shouldn't be calculating the length of the list which i need to 'take' in my recursion, but unsure how to make the 'take' int value set, for example assigning calctake to variable...

```
calctake :: String -> Int
calctake s = length(s) `div` 5

splitintoFive :: String -> [String]
splitintoFive [] = []
splitintoFive xs =  take (calctake xs) xs :  splitintoFive (drop (calctake xs) xs)
```

how can i split a string into a 5 pieces, and create a list of string?

Comment: eg entering splitintoFive "HGBVNJIGFGBNLOP" gives ["HGB","VN","I","G",""]

Comment: You need to calculate the length to take for each chunk once rather than calculating it on each recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a helper function:

```
splitintoFive :: String -> [String]
splitintoFive xs = splitIntoChunksOfLength (calctake xs) xs

splitIntoChunksOfLength :: Int -> String -> [String]
splitIntoChunksOfLength n [] = []
splitIntoChunksOfLength n xs = take n xs : splitIntoChunksOfLength n (drop n xs)
```